# Error No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' - Nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, cors, http-headers

I'm developing an api taking data from a json file that will be inside the project's local files.

I'm having a problem with requests on the front end to get the data, it's a cors error.

In the api I believe I enabled the headers correctly, but I don't know if I have to do it on the front and how I have to do it.

Below will be my code from the index.js file and then the script.js file that will serve to get the data from the api

Main api file that has cors

```
const express = require("express");
const morgan = require("morgan");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

// Routes
const routeLogin = require('./routes/login');
const routeRegister = require('./routes/register');
const routeHashtags = require('./routes/hashtag');

const app = express();



// Use
// Morgan
app.use(morgan("dev"));

// Body parser
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Cors
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-credentials", "true");
  res.header("Acces-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header(
    "Acces-Control-Allow-Header", 
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-CSRF-Token"
  );
  res.header('Acces-Control-Allow-Methods', "GET,OPTIONS, POST, DELETE, PUT, PATCH");

  next();
})



// Routes
app.use('/login', routeLogin);
app.use('/register', routeRegister);
app.use('/hashtag', routeHashtags);

// Error
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const error = new Error("Erro! Não encontrato!");
  error.status = 404;
  next(error);
})

app.use((error, req, res, next) => {
  res.status(error.status || 500);
  return res.send({
    error: {
      message: error.message
    }
  })
})



module.exports = app;
```

Front end

```
async function dashboard(){
  async function pendingPosts(){
    await fetch("http://localhost:3120/hashtag/")
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {console.log(data)})
  }
  pendingPosts()
}
dashboard()
```

Comment: `Access`, not `Acces`, but you already have the `cors` middleware so no need to add headers manually... I believe the code you showed is not actually the code you run though, because you never imported `cors`, yet you are using it, so it should crash!

Comment: Okay, and how should I do this? Just import the cors, ```app.use(cors())```, and delete the headers part?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use

**npm install cors**

var cors = require('cors')

app.use(cors())

try this hope it will help to you

Answer (score 1):

install the cors dependency and then use it is a middleware

```
app.use(cors());
```

After this, if you make a request to your server,  a new header will be  returned as follows,

***`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`***

It determines which origins are allowed to access server resources over CORS.

The * wildcard allows access from any origin or if you want to allow access to particular origin then add origin option to the middleware..

```
app.use(cors({
  origin: 'http://localhost:3000'
}));
```

After this, if you make a request to your server,  a new header will be  returned as follows,
***`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000`***